# Get webpage as PDF exactly how user sees it from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, printing-web-page, webpage-screenshot

The title pretty much sums it up:

I have *no idea* how to get the Data for a PDF of a webpage shown to the user in a WKWebView. Additionally, this PDF must be exactly like what the user sees.

How can I acheive this?

If this is not feasible, then how can I get an image instead (jpg, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the screenshot by doing this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(screenshotSize), false, 0)

self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(screenShotFrame), afterScreenUpdates: true)

let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Now do whatever you wish with the `image`

Comment: but will this work for the entirety of a WKWebView, even the part that is not visible?

Comment: No it only draws only the specified frame with specified width and height.

Comment: Will it work if I give it a frame larger than the screen size?

Comment: You can find out if you try it.

Comment: Are you saying that because you do not know or because you would rather not say?

Comment: Why don't you give it a go? You believe what you see rather than being told by someone.

Comment: Yes it only captures what is visible on screen.